# Evaluate $(1+i)^{2022}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I tried  to solve it by using factorization but still I get stuck midway and don't know what to do.
What I did was, I did $$\left((1+i)^2\right)^{1011}$$ but after that I don't know what to do.
can someone help?

Comment: Hint: Polar form.

Comment: You don't need all that. Once you have $((1+i)^2)^{1011}$, it' easy to multiply $1+i$ by itself, getting $2i$, then render the result as $2^{1011}i^{1011}$. Therefore ... .

Comment: $((1+i)^2)^{1011})=(1+2i-1)^{1011}=(2i)^{1011}=2^{1011}i^{1011} $ now note what i^4 is - can you go further without resorting to polar form?